# How to position a view off-screen in Android layout

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm using the Scene/Transition system introduced in 4.4 to simply move an image view from the left to the center of the screen. So the layout for my first scene requires the image to be off screen. I tried `android:layout_marginRight` but that no effect. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

Use the property `translationX` or `translationY` with a negative value. This property sets the horizontal/vertical location of this view relative to its left/top position. **You will not see the view off screen in the preview.** Run your app and the view must be hidden.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:translationX="-72dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And then in the activity or fragment simply invoke the `animate()` function.

```
    FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.animate().translationX(0);
```

Comment: For some reason, negative values work when they are set in the xml, but setting negative values programatically shrinks the view instead of moving it out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Was thinking one could make the image be to the right of something that is already at the right side, that should keep it off screen.  Also, potentially just make it "gone" and then on transtion make it appear.